# How to make Bltools Projects, using devtools

Tags: javascript, cookies, setup-project

Cookies checker creator (BLTOOLS)

Cookies is Bad..
Your response parameter don't found on your request response..

Try to specify another parameter to validate the good cookies

Please who can help me out

Cookies checker creator (BLTOOLS)

Using devtools.